# How to run verbose rake db:seed Rails 6.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

After successful `rake db:migrate` (which echoes tables creation statuses), I run `rake db:seed`.

But `rake db:seed` does nothing, echoes and returns nothing.

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

is the most I can get.

I identified that some record validation or creation occur, but how can I display these as a result of running rake?

Comment: You could `p`, `puts` things inside the seed file.

Comment: As mentioned by @razvans, I just use some `puts` messages in my `seeds.rb` file to provide output on progress or issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, using puts is a good practice, as well as using create! to raise validation errors instead of having a silent script... Thanks !

Comment: I used to use a flag or something when typing rails db:migrate to see the actual SQL queries